# connecting to a pod from WAN using kubernetes with GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I used Google Cloud Platform to create a Kubernetes 1.8.6 cluster.

I enabled the dashboard and I can login to it properly.

I created a deployment yaml file for mariadb installating

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2 # for versions before 1.8.0 use apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mariadb-deployment
  labels:
    app: mariadb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mariadb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mariadb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mariadb
        image: mariadb:10.3.4
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "<PASSWORD>"
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          value: "<USER>"
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          value: "<PASSWORD>"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          name: mariadb-storage
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
      volumes:
      - name: mariadb-storage
        gcePersistentDisk:
            fsType: ext4
            pdName: mariadb-disk
```

I applied it on kubernetes. now I need to know how to open the mariadb port to my specific WAN ip so i'll be able to connect to it on port 3306.

I can see the endpoint ip of my kubernetes cluster, just no idea how to open permission to be able to connect to it from my desktop's static ip.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do that using the following: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/

since I already have mariadb installed on my local machine so I forwarded port 3306 on remote to be 3307 local using the following:

```
kubectl port-forward mariadb-deployment-<ID> 3307:3306
```

and that's it! i'm able to connect.